# Checking authentication in firebase on OTP

Tags: firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I'm using firebase as my OTP, whenever I log-in thru my app it always send OTP....can I create a code that can check if the number is already signed in on the console so it won't send OTP again??

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically persists and restores the user's credentials when the app is restarted, so you should **not** have to send an OTP each time.

Check on how to detect the user's authentication state for your platform the first snippet in the documentation for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), and [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)